# Group text strings from a list in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to make kws grouping using excel, but my formula is becoming gigantic. I was wondering if there is an easier way to do what I am trying to accomplish here.

I have a list like this below

[image]

And the expected results are as below

[image]

I have tried to use the formula:

```
=if(or(isnumber(search("query kw",A1,1),(isnumber(search("query 2",A1,1)),"Brand kws","Others"))
```

But this formula is becoming gigantic, with the number of queries, so it would be great to have a solution, where the search, would search the kws from a list, and I would only need to keep adding more words there instead.

Thanks for the help

Regards
Gabriel

Answer (score 2):

One way could be:

[image]

Formula in `E2`:

```
=CONCAT(IFERROR(IF(SEARCH(" "&A$2:B$4&" "," "&D2&" "),A$1:B$1,""),""))
```

**Note:** When in Excel 2019 use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another alternative,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

• Formula used in cell **E2**

```
=INDEX($A$1:$B$1,SUM(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(" "&$A$2:$B$4&" "," "&$D2&" "))*(COLUMN($A$1:$B$1))))
```

Since its an array formula, based on your excel version need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> , **O365** & **Excel 2021** Users don't need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>